# Show a list of pages in ListView with XAML binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I have a program with several features. Each feature has a ViewModel, a MainView and OptionsView. MainView is displaying what the feature does, while the OptionsView is a View allowing the user to change the settings of the feature. OptionsView is stored in the MainView.

I want to centralise the Options into a MainOptions view under a ListView. I can get a List or ObservableCollection of the MainViews for each feature, however i have trouble getting the OptionsView of each feature.

I can display OptionsView in the MainView just fine, however when i try to use DataTemplate in a ListView in order to bind the list of MainViews to it and get the OptionViews it doesn't display anything, but it doesn't crash or output errors.

XAML of OptionsMain :

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="OptionsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FeaturesPages, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Transparent">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Frame Name="GroupItemFrame" Content="{Binding Path=OptionsPage, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Code behind :

```
public partial class OptionsMain : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Page> _optionsPages = new ObservableCollection<Page>();

    public ObservableCollection<Page> OptionsPages
    {
        get { return _optionsPages; }
        set
        {
            _optionsPages = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("OptionsPages");
        }
    }

    public OptionsMain(ObservableCollection<Page> pages)
    {
        foreach (Page p in pages)
        {
            OptionsPages.Add(p);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("List size : {0}", OptionsPages.Count);
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
```

Any insight on what might be the problem? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I think you need to have each frame navigate to a page rather than just set its content.

Comment: I do not see how i would do that with XAML and binding, can you please give more details on your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a tricky issue, and I don't see many ways to accomplish this, but I do have a way.  The problem is that you need to call Frame.Navigate to the page for each and every frame.  You can't just assign the content unless it's actually a control with content.  So I am going to suggest a work around/hack of forcing the frame to navigate as it's being loaded.

Mainpage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListBox Name="OptionsList" Background="Transparent">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame Name="GroupItemFrame" Loaded="GroupItemFrame_Loaded" Width="100" Height="100" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Page> MyPages = new List<Page>();
        MyPages.Add(new DisplayNumberPage());
        MyPages.Add(new DisplayNumberPage());
        MyPages.Add(new DisplayNumberPage());
        MyPages.Add(new DisplayNumberPage());
        MyPages.Add(new DisplayNumberPage());
        OptionsList.ItemsSource = MyPages;
    }

    int Index = 1;
    private void GroupItemFrame_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame MyFrame = sender as Frame;
        MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(DisplayNumberPage), Index);
        Index++;
    }
}
```

DisplayNumberPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <TextBlock x:Name="DisplayNumber" FontSize="30" Text="100" Foreground="White"/>
</Grid>
```

DispayNumberPage.xaml.cs:

```
  public sealed partial class DisplayNumberPage : Page
{
    public DisplayNumberPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayNumber.Text = e.Parameter.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand the MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(DisplayNumberPage), Index); line. How are you passing it the instance of the object in the list?

Comment: Although i haven't used the exact solution you proposed (the Navigate(typeof(...), Index); part), it did solve my problem. Solution accepted.

Comment: Yes I understand that it's not the exact instance, but I think you probably just recreated the instance in the loaded method.  Glad to have helped here.

Comment: Actually i use the index to give the instance in the list to the Navigate function, since there is an overload that takes an object as parameter.

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an answer so it can be visible. 
I found the optimal answer to my question after i used the answer marked as correct. They both work, it's just another way, simpler i'd argue, to achieve the same result:

```
 <ListBox Name="OptionsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OptionsPages, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Transparent">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Name="OptionsItemStack" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Name="GroupItemLabel" Content="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Frame Name="GroupItemFrame" Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Notice the Content="{Binding}". It doesn't need a code behind to display the Page in the frame.
As stated, it was tested and works, no errors in the output either.